# Is it possible to generate an executable (.exe) of a jupyter-notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, exe, executable

I wrote a code in python using jupyter notebook and i want to generate an executable of the program.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use this code I've written to convert large numbers of `.ipynb` files into `.py` files.

```
srcFolder = r'input_folderpath_here'
desFolder = r'output_folderpath_here'

import os
import nbformat
from nbconvert import PythonExporter

def convertNotebook(notebookPath, modulePath):
    with open(notebookPath) as fh:
        nb = nbformat.reads(fh.read(), nbformat.NO_CONVERT)
    exporter = PythonExporter()
    source, meta = exporter.from_notebook_node(nb)
    with open(modulePath, 'w+') as fh:
        fh.writelines(source)

# For folder creation if doesn't exist
if not os.path.exists(desFolder):
    os.makedirs(desFolder)

for file in os.listdir(srcFolder):
    if os.path.isdir(srcFolder + '\\' + file):
        continue
    if ".ipynb" in file:
        convertNotebook(srcFolder + '\\' + file, desFolder + '\\' + file[:-5] + "py")
```

Once you have converted your `.ipynb` files into `.py` files.
Try running the `.py` files to ensure they work.
After which, use Pyinstaller in your terminal or command prompt.
`cd` to your `.py` file location.
And then type

```
pyinstaller --onefile yourfile.py
```

This will generate a single file `.exe` program

Answer (score 19):

No, *however* it is possible to generate a `.py` script from `.ipynb`, which can **then** be converted to a .exe

With [jupyter nbconvert](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html?highlight=executable#convert-script) 
(If you are using Anaconda, this is already included)

In the environment :

```
pip install nbconvert
jupyter nbconvert --to script my_notebook.ipynb
```

Will generate a `my_notebook.py`.

Then with [Pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org) :

```
pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller my_notebook.py
```

You should now have a `my_notebook.exe` and dist files in your folder.

Source: A slightly outdated [Medium Article about this](https://medium.com/@erdmyzn/convert-jupyter-ipynb-to-python-py-and-python-py-to-file-exe-265329d9be95)

Comment: There are some pitfalls for pyinstaller when using pandas. I wrote a detailed step-by-step tutorial how to create a one-file executable (.py -> .exe) here: https://geo.rocks/post/python-to-exe/.