# Python executable file closes without showing outputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, exe, google-books

I created a code that use Google Books API on Jupiter in python language. I would like to create an .exe file in order to use it on other PCs. I did it with `pyinstaller name_of_the_script.py`, but when I execute it after I entered the second input, the command window disappears without showing outputs, also if I put an input line at the end in order to keep alive the script until I press a key.

Here the code:

```
import requests

quote = input('Inserisci la citazione: ')
lingua = input('\nInserisci lingua (sigla, ad esempio ''it'' per ''Italiano''): ')


key = 'xxxxxxxxx'
parms = {'q':quote, 'key':key, 'maxResults':5,'langRestrict':lingua}

r = requests.get(url='https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes', params = parms)
rj = r.json()

for i in range(0,3):
    print('\n' + rj['items'][i]['volumeInfo']['title'] + '\n')
    for authors in rj['items'][i]['volumeInfo']['authors']:
        print(authors)
    print('\n' + '\n')

input('press enter to quit')
```

What is wrong?

Comment: It probably crashed during execution. Can you add a `try catch` statement around your code and try again? This is one of the issues with working with `pyinstaller`...

Comment: I will try. An what if I didn't consider something? For example should I put in the same folder of the .exe the libraries that I used? I am sorry but I am not a programmer.

Comment: I forgot to ask: does it run fine when you run it in Python, without running the .exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved!

It was an error in the conversion of the .ipynb file into .py file.
To convert it I used a code found here in SO and now it works.

Here the post that helped me:

[Is it possible to generate an executable (.exe) in a jupyter-notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55741607/is-it-possible-to-generate-an-executable-exe-in-a-jupyter-notebook)