# How could I run ipynb file on my device like a game icon?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, exe

I know this question might sound very primitive

How could U run an ipynb file on a device that doesn't have jupyter or python installed?
to ask the question properly (which format do I need to convert my ipynb file to so it could run normally as if it was a game without the need to install python or Jupyter?)  (like .exe when you install a program for example)

If not available then can I run it on web ? wihtout showing the coding just an interactive mode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to generate an executable (.exe) in a jupyter-notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55741607/is-it-possible-to-generate-an-executable-exe-in-a-jupyter-notebook)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to first, covert your `ipynb` into a python file, then convert that python file into and `.exe`:

**1. Convert `ipynb` into `.py`**

```
pip install nbconvert
jupyter nbconvert --to script your_notebook.ipynb
```

The output of the above is `your_notebook.py`

**2. Convert `.py` to `.exe`**

```
pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller your_notebook.py
```

You should now have a `your_notebook.exe` which you can open by double click