# How can I create an executable out of jupyter notebook code?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

**My use-case is** - To visualize the peer feedback of staff to find interesting facts and inferences.

Ex - reading data from a .csv file and creating visualization on the feedback like a word cloud, bar charts, spider charts, etc.

**The expected end-user experience is -**

a) User clicks on the executable

b) User is asked to select a file

c) User sees all the visualizations

Also, in the future, I want to give the option for users to apply filters and search for categorical variables & staff nos.

**ps: I want to keep tools like power bi, MicroStrategy, etc out of scope for this PoC.**

Comment: Despite your title, an executable doesn't seem to be what you want. Given your description, you seem to be wanting a Dashboard-like interface backed by a notebook or notebooks. See about Voila, nbinteract, Panel, or Dash . See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/hosting-interactive-jupyter-html-file-with-ipywidgets-on-github-as-web-page/8361/2?u=fomightez), [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/showcase-deploying-panel-highchart-apps-on-binder/8629), [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/panel-v0-12-0-adds-jupyterlab-preview/10053) for more about those.

Comment: Continued... Or [here](https://github.com/plotly/jupyter-dash). Or [the Voila Gallery](https://voila-gallery.org/).

Comment: Plus, there is [nteract Desktop App](https://nteract.io/applications) and [thebe](https://github.com/executablebooks/thebe). Thebe can use a local Jupyter server as kernel provider, see [here](https://thebe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_static/html_examples/local.html). When mentioning online applications, like Voila earlier, I should have included [Appmode](https://github.com/oschuett/appmode).

Comment: Plus you may be interested in [this discussion](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/is-it-possible-to-convert-jupyer-notebook-ipynb-file-to-desktop-app/11590/2?u=fomightez).

Answer (score 2):

There does not seem to be a direct way to convert a Jupyter notebook to an executable file.

However the standard way to tackle your problem seems to be a two-step process:

1. convert the notebook into a regular Python script. You can download your notebook as a Python script from the Jupyter GUI or use `nbconvert`, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55741607/is-it-possible-to-generate-an-executable-exe-of-a-jupyter-notebook) is related.
2. turn the script into an executable. There are several tools available for that matter, such as Cx_freeze or Pyinstaller.

Comment: I have a feeling that he doesn't have the UI/UX to interact with the code. btw I agree with your solutuon