# Getting NameError: name 'null' is not defined after converting .ipynb to .exe file

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, ipython, pyinstaller

I am using pyinstaller to convert .ipynb file to .exe file as i want my peers members to use it without depending on python but when i try to run the exe file i get the following error

***Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Bot.ipynb", line 232, in 
NameError: name 'null' is not defined***

Two things to consider here are

1. I dont have this particular keyword "null"
2. my total line of codes are less than 232

Here is my piece of code:

```
from tkinter import *
import PIL
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image
import tkinter as tk
import webbrowser
from tkinter import scrolledtext
from datetime import datetime

root = tk.Tk()
def update_title():
    current_date_time = datetime.now().strftime("%A,%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S")
    root.title(f"Welcome -  {current_date_time}")
    root.after(1000, update_title)
    
update_title()   
root.geometry("1000x700")
root.configure(bg="#D22730")

def open_website(url):
    webbrowser.open(url)


# Function to handle user input and generate bot response
def get_bot_response():
    user_input = input_box.get("1.0", tk.END).strip().lower()
    output_box.configure(state='normal')
    output_box.delete("1.0",tk.END) # Clear previous output
    output_box.insert(tk.END, 'User: {}\n'.format(user_input))
    
    # Check user queries and provide instructions accordingly
     
        
    if 'how to register to ekincare' in user_input or 'ekincare' in user_input or 'medicine' in 
      user_input or 'tele-medicine' in user_input:
        instructions =  "partnered with ekincare, a leading digital healthcare provider 
        to provide you with 24/7 unlimited access to doctor consultation. The coverage is for the 
        employee and upto 5 family members. \n\n" 
        instructions += "The key services provided are: \n"
        instructions += "1.  24/7 unlimited teleconsultation – (General Physician only) via chat or audio \n"
        instructions += "2.  Health Risk Assessment – Track your and your family’s health \n"
        instructions += "3.  COVID Care Management- Home Isolation support for COVID treatment \n"
        instructions += "4.  Discounted Pharmacy –  Up to 20% discount on medicines ordered online (borne by the employee) \n"
        instructions += "5.  Discounted Medical Tests - Up to 40% discount on home sample collection (borne by the employee) \n"
        instructions += "6.  For any queries / support required, please reach out to ekincare at help@ekincare.com or call at +91 49 6816 7274 \n"   
        instructions += "7.  For more details, please refer: https://hrdirect.service-now.com/sys_attachment.do?sys_id=f3c0bd451b37959868314376b04bcbf9 \n"
        

        response = instructions     
        
    elif 'how to add a new domestic beneficiary using mobile banking app' in user_input or 'payee' in user_input or 'add beneficiary' in user_input:
        instructions = "To add new benefiary, please follow the below steps. \n\n" 
        instructions += "1.  Login to your Mobile Banking App \n"
        instructions += "2.  Select 'Move Money' tab \n"
        instructions += "3.  Select 'Pay & Transfer' \n"
        instructions += "4.  Choose the account you’re making the payment from \n"
        instructions += "5.  Under the 'my beneficiaries' section Now you’ll see an option to 'Add a new beneficiary' at the top of your screen \n"
        instructions += "6.  Select and follow the onscreen instructions \n"   
        instructions += "7.  'Confirm' your instruction \n"
        

        response = instructions  
        
    else:
        response = "Sorry, I need to get trained on this topic"
        
    output_box.insert(tk.END, 'Bot: {}\n'.format(response))
    output_box.configure(state='disabled')
    output_box.see(tk.END)
    
input_label = tk.Label(root, text="User Input:",anchor="w",bg="black",fg="white",font=("Arial",12))
input_label.pack(anchor="w")

    
# Input Box
input_box = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, height=7, width=100,font=("Arial",12))
input_box.pack()

output_label = tk.Label(root, text="Bot Response:",anchor="w",bg="black",fg="white",font=("Arial",12))
output_label.pack(anchor="w")

# Output
output_box = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, height=15,width=100,wrap=tk.WORD,font=("Arial",12))
output_box.pack()    
output_box.configure(borderwidth=1, relief="solid")

#button_font = font.Font(size=12,"bold")
send_button = tk.Button(root, text="Find", command=get_bot_response,bg="black",fg="white",width=8,height=1, font=("Arial",12,"bold"))
send_button.pack()

button_frame = tk.Frame(root)
button_frame.pack(side="bottom",pady=10)
    
button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Service now", relief="flat",width=15, height=1,font=("Arial",10,"bold"),command=lambda: open_website("https://itid.service-now.com/servicenow")) 
button1.pack(side="left",padx=5)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Full traceback]

Comment: Is that the whole traceback?

Comment: Yes, i am adding image as well

Comment: can anyone please help ?

Comment: Can you share your setup file too?

Comment: You should try copy/pasting your code out of a notebook and put it into a normal `.py` file before doing the compilation. The underlying representation of the notebook is likely to be JSON that's being preserved for whatever reason, which will be why you're getting a `null` and an error on a line that "doesn't exist" - it does in the json representation. Even without this error, I suspect the code will just be a JSON blob anyway and not do anything

Comment: @Thingmabobs : How can i share the setup file on this platform ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is most likely due to the fact that you're trying to go directly from an `.ipynb` to an executable. Your first port of call should just be to copy/paste your code out of the notebook and into an ordinary `.py` file before you try the conversion.

The reason being is that notebooks have an underlying JSON representation - see [here](https://nbformat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format_description.html).  What's likely happening is that the raw JSON is being saved and then, when you call the file, it gets passed through the python interpreter. This explains both observations:

1. There will be a literal `null` value, which is valid in JSON but not in Python. If you use the `json` module, it will convert them to `None` for you, but that deserialization step isn't happening here because it's being treated as a pure python object
2. There are way more lines to your actual code than you expect. When everything is expanded into that JSON schema that I linked, it's very simple to see that your code could have a line `232` even though it's not in the representation that your IDE is displaying.

Even if your `.exe` *didn't* throw an error, I suspect the best you could hope for is an unnamed python dictionary that doesn't actually execute any of the code it contains.

There are other answers about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55741607/is-it-possible-to-generate-an-executable-exe-of-a-jupyter-notebook) but I suspect it's not so easy to connect your error to the underlying problem directly.

Comment: This makes sense, in my case what would be the best way of converting .ipynvb to .py file , simply downloading it as .py file wont work ?

Comment: As I said in the first line of my answer, just copy/paste the code out of the file; it's highly unlikely that your notebook is in any kind of pipeline so there doesn't need to be a programmatic way to do it. I also gave a link to other answers that give different approaches